# can't read quotes correctly with pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file test.tsv with some rows having quotes and it basically skips stops using the new line character as a new row indicator. So if I have a file

```
" m     1
what does comoda mean   1
the poke co     1
dmf     1
"g      1
```

and I use

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.tsv", 
                  sep='\t')
```

I get the all rows as one row

```
 m\t1\nwhat does comoda mean\t1\nthe poke co\t1\ndmf\t1\ng  1
```

I want to keep all rows intact and get the output

```
" m     1
what does comoda mean   1
the poke co     1
dmf     1
"g      1
```

Is there a way to solve this double quote issue? I have multiple rows coming out as a single row wherever I have double quotes opened up until there is double quote to close that. After that the rows are interpreted correctly.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe containing exactly the output you want? I'm not clear on what you mean by "get the output like we have the input".

Comment: `\n` means a new line. is this your whole tsv file?

Comment: No I just put a sample in.

Comment: Basically I have multiple rows and all of them now are coming out as one row after reading.

Comment: Separator in your csv file is \t ??

Comment: Yes it is \t I added one more column hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the parsing of quotes using the `quoting` keyword parameter of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). In your case you can disable quoting like so:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import csv

>>> pd.read_csv("test.tsv", sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)                 

                     " m  1
0  what does comoda mean  1
1            the poke co  1
2                    dmf  1
3                     "g  1
```

Note that the first row is being interpreted as a column header. Pass `header=None` to prevent that.